# Next Js "No overload matches this call"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, next-auth

i currently using nextjs 14, i having a problem on onSuccess section keep showing no overload matches this call, need help and guide on this.

the program language i using.

```
npm: '10.4.0',
  node: '21.6.1',
  acorn: '8.11.3',
  ada: '2.7.4',
  ares: '1.20.1',
  base64: '0.5.1',
  brotli: '1.1.0',
  cjs_module_lexer: '1.2.2',
  cldr: '44.0',
  icu: '74.1',
  llhttp: '9.1.3',
  modules: '120',
  napi: '9',
  nghttp2: '1.58.0',
  nghttp3: '0.7.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.8.1',
  openssl: '3.0.12+quic',
  simdjson: '3.6.3',
  simdutf: '4.0.8',
  tz: '2023c',
  undici: '5.28.2',
  unicode: '15.1',
  uv: '1.47.0',
  uvwasi: '0.0.19',
  v8: '11.8.172.17-node.19',
  zlib: '1.3.0.1-motley-40e35a7'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlJzI.png)

```
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation"
import { trpc } from "../_trpc/client"

const Page = async () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
  const origin = searchParams.get('origin')


  const {data, isLoading} = trpc.authCallback.useQuery(undefined, {
    onSuccess: ({success}) => {      <==== error here
      if(success) {
        router.push(origin ? `/${origin}` : '/dashboard')
      }
    }
  })
  

}

export default Page
```

the error code

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(input: void, opts: DefinedUseTRPCQueryOptions<{ success: boolean; }, { success: boolean; }, TRPCClientErrorLike<{ errorShape: DefaultErrorShape; transformer: false; }>, { ...; }>): DefinedUseTRPCQueryResult<...>', gave the following error.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'onSuccess' does not exist in type 'DefinedUseTRPCQueryOptions<{ success: boolean; }, { success: boolean; }, TRPCClientErrorLike<{ errorShape: DefaultErrorShape; transformer: false; }>, { success: boolean; }>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(input: void, opts?: UseTRPCQueryOptions<{ success: boolean; }, { success: boolean; }, TRPCClientErrorLike<{ input: void; output: { success: boolean; }; transformer: false; errorShape: DefaultErrorShape; }>, { ...; }> | undefined): UseTRPCQueryResult<...>', gave the following error.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'onSuccess' does not exist in type 'UseTRPCQueryOptions<{ success: boolean; }, { success: boolean; }, TRPCClientErrorLike<{ input: void; output: { success: boolean; }; transformer: false; errorShape: DefaultErrorShape; }>, { ...; }>'.ts(2769)
```

i expect to solve only "onSuccess: ({success})" error section.

Comment: May be due to this ? [`Callbacks on useQuery (and QueryObserver) have been removed `](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/guides/migrating-to-v5#callbacks-on-usequery-and-queryobserver-have-been-removed)